# How do i stop bjqs slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bjqs

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    function init_slider() {
        $('#date_ss').bjqs({
            animtype: 'fade',
            autoplay: autoPlay,
            animduration: -1,
            animspeed: 4000,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 900,
            keyboardnav: goTo,
            responsive: false,
            showcontrols: false,
            showmarkers: false,
            centercontrols: false
        });
    }
    init_slider();
});
```

I am using this. goTo is flag i am using to enable and disable keyboard navigation. I problem is that slider is auto rotate i want to stop it.

Comment: Hii,  your requirement is to stop auto rotation feature of this  bjqs slider..right??

Comment: yes you are right. I want to stop auto rotation feature of bjqs slider. @Jacky Coogan

Comment: Try 'automatic       : false'

Comment: I have not enough votes to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I think,

```
automatic       : false
```

will solve the issue...

Within this bjqs slider(bjqs-1.3.js) we can see the following declaration,

```
automatic       : false,     // enable/disable automatic slide rotation
```

Modified code,

```
$(document).ready(function (){
function init_slider() {
    $('#date_ss').bjqs({
        animtype: 'fade',
        autoplay: autoPlay,
        automatic: false,
        animduration: -1,
        animspeed: 4000,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 900,
        keyboardnav: goTo,
        responsive: false,
        showcontrols: false,
        showmarkers: false,
        centercontrols: false
    });
}
init_slider();
```

});